# Are smooth functions dense in the space $\{u \in H^1(Q) \text{ with } \Delta_\Gamma u \in L^2(Q)\}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces

Define $$Q = \bigcup_{t \in (0,T)}\Gamma \times \{t\}$$ where $\Gamma$ is a compact (without boundary) hypersurface. Assume whatever smoothness is required.

Define $L^2(Q) := L^2(0,T;L^2(\Gamma))$ and $$H^1(Q) := \{ u \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Gamma)) : u_t \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Gamma)) \}.$$

Given a function $u \in H^1(Q)$ with $\Delta_\Gamma u \in L^2(Q)$, is it possible to find smooth functions (at least $C^2$ in space and $C^1$ in time) such that
$$u_n \to u \quad \text{ in $H^1(Q)$}$$
$$\Delta_\Gamma u_n \to \Delta_\Gamma u \quad \text{ in $L^2(Q)$}$$

Here $\nabla_\Gamma$ is the usual surface or tangential gradient and $\Delta_\Gamma$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator.Note that the first requested convergence means 
$u_n \to u$, $\nabla_\Gamma u_n \to \nabla_\Gamma u,$ and $(u_n)_t \to u_t$ all in $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Gamma)).$

I don't know how to even start this problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think the question is off-topic here as not research level. There is a standard procedure for proving density of (equivalence classes of) smooth functions in spaces of some order weakly differentiable (equivalence classes of) functions on manifolds: Take a partition of unity and approximate the "bumps on patches" separately by taking a convolution with suitably chosen smooth functions with small compact support. Formal details should be found in books handling PDEs on manifolds.

Comment: The point is it's not clear if this result holds for the case when $\Gamma = \Omega$ is a standard domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm not asking about how to transfer results on Euclidean space to manifolds.

Comment: @ student: I don't understand your comment. Your manifold is $Q=\Gamma\times{]}0,T{[}$, and your function space over this manifold is formed by (equivalence classes of) functions in $L^2(Q)$ such that also the first order weak derivatives along both factors together with the Laplacian along the first factor are in $L^2(Q)$ . I see no reason why you could not apply the standard method for proving density of the set of (equivalence classes of) smooth functions.

Comment: @TaQ Ok. The details are not that clear to me. If you would care to answer here or in the MSE thread I opened (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693183/an-equality-that-holds-with-v-t-in-l20-tl2-omega-but-its-proof-require/693230?noredirect=1#comment1452742_693230) I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my first comment I wrote: "I think the question is off-topic here as not research level." Since there have been no other comments in that direction, and no (visible) downvotes, maybe the question then is on-topic anyway.

I have read the OP's questions and comments also in MSE, and there seems to be a similar, but not quite the same problem. Here (in MO) the problem is formulated as possible density of the set of (equivalence classes containing) smooth functions in a space $W(Q)$ for $Q=\Gamma\times J_T$ with $J_T={]}0,T{[}$ such that the elements of $W(Q)$ are (equivalence classes of) functions in $L^2(Q)$ having also first order weak partial derivatives and the weak "space" Laplacian in $L^2(Q)$ . In MSE, in place of the compact (smooth) hypersurface $\Gamma$ there is (if I understand correctly) an open set $\Omega$ in a Euclidean space. Moreover, in the MSE formulation, the space is defined by requiring all second order partials "in the space direction" to be in $L^2(Q)$ , not just the Laplacian.

The possible validity of the equation
$$
\int_Q \varphi^2 (\Delta v)v_t = \int_Q |\nabla v|^2 \varphi \varphi_t - 2\int_Q (\nabla v \cdot \nabla \varphi) (\varphi v_t)\kern30mm (*)
$$
seems to be the source of the density problem. It holds if $v$ is known to be smooth, and by continuity, it also holds for $v$ in $W(Q)$ if density the set of smooth functions in the space $W(Q)$ can be established. By elliptic regularity, the two slightly different formulations are actually equivalent since only integration over a compact set occurs in $(*)$ as $\varphi$ has compact support. Namely, by Theorem 20.1 on page 308 in Wloka's *Partial Differential Equations*, CUP 1992, the elements in $W(Q)$ actually have also all second order weak space partials in $L^2(Q)$ .

So all that has to be done, if I have understood everything correctly, is to prove density of the set of (equivalence classes containing) smooth functions in the space $W(Q)$ that is naturally linearly homeomorphic to the space one would usually write  e.g. as $H^1(J_T,L^2(\Gamma))\cap L^2(J_T,H^2(\Gamma))$ .

A decent proof would require too much effort. So I give only a sequence of remarks as hints hoping that a mathematically matured reader could then write a proof himself if he wished.

Arbitrarily fix an element $u$ in $W(Q)$ . Since in ($*$) only integration over a compact subset of $Q$ is involved, by multiplying with a suitable "cut-off" function "in the time direction", we may assume $u$ defined on $\Gamma\times\mathbb R$ with support contained in some $\Gamma\times[\varepsilon,T-\varepsilon]$ . Cover $\Gamma$ with finitely many coordinate patches, and take a partition of unity subordinate to this covering. Then $u$ is expressed as a finite sum of functions $u_k$ with the same regularity properties as $u$ . Moreover, each $u_k$ has its support in some $U_k\times[\varepsilon,T-\varepsilon]$ where $U_k$ is the domain of a chart $\phi_k:U_k\to\mathbb R^{\,n}$ of $\Gamma$ . Letting $v_k$ be the zero extension of $(x,t)\mapsto u_k(\phi_k^{-1}(x),t)$ to $\mathbb R^{\,n}\times\mathbb R$ , then $v_k$ has the same regularity as $u$ . If each $v_k$ can be approximated by a smooth function $\varphi_k$ in the sense that the $L^2(\mathbb R^{\,n}\times\mathbb R)$ norms of $\varphi_k-v_k$ and all its first order derivatives and second order "space" derivatives become small, and also the support of $\varphi_k$ is sufficiently close to that of $v_k$ , then taking $\varphi=\sum_k\varphi_k^0$ with $\varphi_k^0$ the zero extension to $\Gamma\times J_T$ of $U_k\times J_T\owns(z,t)\mapsto\varphi_k(\phi_k(z),t)$ , we have $\varphi$ smooth with the $W(Q)$ norm of $\varphi-u$ small. The required approximation is possible e.g. by Wloka's Theorem 1.3 on page 9 loc. cit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The last two sentences are the crux of the argument. We need to know that $\lVert \varphi_k - v_k \rVert_{H^1(\mathbb R^{n+1})} + |\varphi_k(t)-v_k(t)|_{H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ can be made arbitrarily small. The theorem you quoted (Wloka's Theorem 1.3) only gives us that the $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$ norm can be made small. I guess I would need to look at eg. the proof that $C^\infty$ is dense in $H^1$ and adapt it to get what is required.

Comment: @ student: Yes. For more details, see e.g. Wloka's Lemma 3.3 on pages 66−67 and Theorem 1.11 on page 21, or Lemma 3.15 on page 52 in Robert A. Adams' (1975 edition of) *Sobolev Spaces*.